# Managing team permissions and allowing two users from the same team to access a node

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I allow login with Google to my Firebase web app.
I control access to the database by the auth.uid:

```
 {
  "rules": {
     "users": {
        "$uid": {          
          ".read": "auth.uid === $uid",
          ".write":"auth.uid !== null",
             "images": {
                ".read": "auth.uid === $uid",
                ".write":"auth.uid === $uid",
      },
 ...
```

I want to enable other users in the user's team to access his/her images. I went through the docs but couldn't find a way to accomplish that. Any ideas?

Comment: i highly recommend checking out the "5 neat tricks talk with Firebase" talk from Google I/O where Todd covers precisely this scenario in [neat trick #2](https://youtu.be/5hYMDfDoHpI?t=9m13s).

Comment: neat trick #2, exactly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Security rules are able to read data from other keys, so it's possible to construct rules that are based upon the existence of a key (i.e. membership of a team).

What's below is a small fragment of the [Bolt](https://github.com/firebase/bolt) rules that I've used for a Firebase database:

```
path /teams/{$teamKey}/members/{$userId} is Boolean {
    ...
}

path /users/{$userId}/shares/{$teamKey} {
    ...
    read() { root.teams[$teamKey].members[auth.uid] !== null }
}
```

The JSON would look something like this:

```
...
"users": {
  "$userId": {
    ...
    "shares": {
      "$teamKey": {
        ...
        ".read": "root.child('teams').child($teamKey).child('members').child(auth.uid).val() != null",
        ...
```

Hopefully, that will make some sense. Basically, there is a key for a team and it contains user ids (with boolean values). And read access to shared information under a user's key is granted to other team members by verifying their membership - that is, by checking for the existence of a user id key under the team key. Essentially, you store the data that drives the security rules in the database itself.

You don't have to use Bolt, but I find it much easier to manage than the JSON representation. The Bolt language documentation contains information on the [RuleDataSnapshot Methods](https://github.com/firebase/bolt/blob/master/docs/language.md#ruledatasnapshot-methods) for both the Bolt definitions and the JSON definitions.

Comment: Thank you, you're answer is clear. Do you give permissions to add members to a team to a specific uid?

Comment: Yes. You can extend the concept as far as you need to take it. When a user creates a team, they become the owner and the owner has write permissions for them team members. You can also use the mechanism to manage read permissions - so that only team members can see the other members.